# Handle soft keys action in LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit, keypress, nokia

I'm developing an application for Nokia C2 Mobile and I want to handle the soft keys of the keyboard

Attached an image with the button that I want to handle

I have tried Handle KeyPressed and the keycode that returned when I press this button is 0

please what should I do ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button pointed is `Right Soft Key (RSK)`. In that picture, they `added commands GoTo, Menu and Names`. Just like that, add commands to the form. Type the code to handle that event in command listener.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have made it, but I need to change the style of the bar of command buttons in LWUIT, could you please tell me how can I do that ???